# Assess damage to wooden floor

Tags: wood, parquet

My new place has scratches on large areas of the floor, mainly around the entrance and the patio door. 
The floor is also chipped in some places, not necessarily where the scratches are.

Can I just put carpets on the floor if I don't want to sand it? Thank you.
[image: scratches]

Answer (score 1):

Throw rugs will work but you'll probably end up wanting to sand and fix it right. If you do wall to wall make sure to use padding.

Comment: And to answer the implied question, you can ignore this minor damage to the floor, it's not dangerous.